# Delete the first n bytes of a file in O(n) time

Tags: files, filesystems

I've been browsing around looking for a solution for a personal project (Read: a coding experiment), but nothing quite seems to fit. To be honest, I don't even know if it's possible.

Now, there's simply no way to do this based on the whole file. Anything that is based on writing a new file without those first n bytes, even if it's in place, obviously isn't going to work. The only thing I can think of is somehow telling the file system that the beginning of the file is now further along, and wiping out the beginning of it.

But like I said, I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: I can't see this possible, unless you rewrite code for filesystem including a new system call.

Comment: The answer to this question is going to be highly dependent on the underlying file system.  If you're working with one which has a byte pointer marking the start of the file, then you can truncate the beginning of the file in O(1) time by simply moving the pointer.  But I doubt that (m)any modern random-access file systems work like this.

Comment: on `ext4` you can free some space at the beginning with `fallocate -p`. The virtual file size will remain the same, but it won't occupy space

Comment: You can also do `losetup --offset x file`, then map the loop device as a regular file with https://github.com/vasi/diskfile

Comment: Thanks @basin, unfortunately I'm new here so I can't vote on comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete bytes from a file you have to rewrite it. That will be O(L) time where L is the length of the file. You will never achieve O(n) in a sane file system.

You might reach `< O(n)` when n is divisible by the file systems block size as this operation will just remove some reserved inodes from the directory entry.
(In the ideal case, where a program exactly does that!)

Comment: You possibly misunderstand the word “inode” (at least wrongly use it in plural). Also, directories are irrelevant.